# objective-C: mismatched method and syntax

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

I'm trying to create a sectioned table. I've got two parsed NSMutableArrays feedsTopics and feedsSchools who reside in my mainAppDelegate.

In my tableViewController, I create an appDelegate representing my app's delegate:

```
appDelegate = (mainAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

I'm trying to declare topics and schools as arrays like so (which is an ERROR that reads, "No known class method for selector 'appDelegate'", just saying that's what I've gotten to):

```
NSArray *topics = [[NSArray appDelegate] feedsTopics];
```

which I want to add as a dictionary object to NSMutableArray listOfItems like so (this has an error saying it "expects an identifier"):

```
NSDictionary *topicsDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:appDelegate.feedsTopics forKey:[@"News by Topic"];
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: What am I doing wrong? "No known class method for selector 'appDelegate'", and "expects an identifier"...

Comment: Please post some context to the code above. First error looks like you have an open `[` bracket before the `appDelegate` assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first error is caused by calling a `appDelegate` method of `NSArray` - this does not exist. The second error is caused by a misplaced `[`.

Your code should look like this:

```
NSArray *topics = [appDelegate feedsTopics];
```

and

```
NSDictionary *topicsDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:topics forKey:@"News by Topic"];
```

By the way: Your errors do not relate to tableViews at all. I'd suggest to edit the title of this question.

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by line:

```
NSArray *topics = [[NSArray appDelegate] feedsTopics];
```

NSArray does not have a method "appDelegate".

Comment: Thank you, I have figured it out!